# How to aggregate data without group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregation

I am having a little bit of a situation here.

### The environment

I have a database for series here.
One table for the series itself, one for the season connected to the series table, one for the episodes connected to the seasons table.
Since there are air dates for different countries I have another table called 'series_data` which looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `episode_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `episode_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `tba` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `episode_id` (`episode_id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `country` (`country`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now I am trying to collect the last aired episodes from each series in the database using the following query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `episode_data` ed
WHERE
    `ed`.`date` < CURDATE( ) &&
    `ed`.`date` != '1970-01-01' &&
    `ed`.`series_id` = 1
GROUP BY
    `ed`.`country` DESC
ORDER BY
    `ed`.`date` DESC
```

Since I have everything normalized I changed 'episode_id' with 'series_id' to make the query less complicated.

### What I am trying to accomplish

I want to have the last aired episodes for each country which are actually announced (`ed`.`date` != '1970-01-01') as the returning result of one query.

### What's the problem

I know now (searched google, found not for me working answers here), that the ordering takes place AFTER grouping, so my "date" ordering is completly useless.

The other problem is that the query above is working, but always takes those entries with the lowest id matching my conditions, because those are the first ones in the tables index.

### What is the question?

How may accomplish the above. I do not know if the grouping is the right way to do it. If there is no "one liner", I think the only way is a sub query which I want to avoid since this is as far as I know slower than a one liner with the right indexes set.

Hope in here is everything you need :)

### Example data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `episode_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `episode_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `tba` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `episode_id` (`episode_id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `country` (`country`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `episode_data` (`id`, `episode_id`, `country`, `title`, `date`, `tba`) VALUES
(4942, 2471, 'de', 'Väter und Töchter', '2013-08-06', 0),
(4944, 2472, 'de', 'Neue Perspektiven', '2013-08-13', 0),
(5013, 2507, 'us', 'Into the Deep', '2013-08-06', 0),
(5015, 2508, 'us', 'The Mirror Has Three Faces', '2013-08-13', 0);
```

**Attention!**
This is the original table data with "EPISODE_ID" not "SERIES_ID".

The data I want are those with closest dates to today, which are here 4944 and 5015.

Comment: we need  a sample data and wished result. if possible in fidle

Comment: Done. If you meant jsFiddle, I do not know how this makes any sense, because it is for JS.
I added it here.

Comment: What echo_Me meant is sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Ah, thx. Seems broken though ^^ Can not create schema.

Comment: The underlying DB seems to be down, sadly :"Schema Creation Failed: can't connect to datasource [sqlfiddle_mysql2]: Server connection failure during transaction. Due to underlying exception: 'java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused'."

Comment: Read that, too. Seems like localhost is your best friend again ^^

Comment: So no one has an idea to this??

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last aired date for each country, then use this aggregation:

```
SELECT country, max(date) as lastdate
FROM `episode_data` ed
WHERE `ed`.`date` < CURDATE( ) AND
      `ed`.`date` != '1970-01-01' AND
      `ed`.`series_id` = 1
GROUP BY `ed`.`country`;
```

If you are trying to get the `episode_id` and `title` as well, you can use `group_concat()` and `substring_index()`:

```
SELECT country, max(date) as lastdate,
       substring_index(group_concat(episode_id order by date desc), ',', 1
                      ) as episode_id,
       substring_index(group_concat(title order by date desc separator '|'), '|', 1
                      ) as title
FROM `episode_data` ed
WHERE `ed`.`date` < CURDATE( ) AND
      `ed`.`date` != '1970-01-01' AND
      `ed`.`series_id` = 1
GROUP BY `ed`.`country`;
```

Note that this uses a different separator for the title, under the assumption that it might have a comma.

Comment: Thanks, but the first query is not working.

Why do I need to group_concat that stuff? Why can't i just select it?